# Can't catch UnauthorizedAccessException (complains about inaccessible constructor)

Tags: windows, exception, c++-cli, system

I'm trying to catch an UnauthorizedAccessException, but

```
catch(UnauthorizedAccessException uae)
{
    return FALSE;
}
```

gives the compiler error "unable to throw or catch a managed object by value or reference" and "cannot be caught as the destructor and/or copy constructor are inaccessible". If I try to catch as a pointer to the exception or by reference, it complains this exception cannot be handled by such a level of indirection.

Comment: Is this a CLI thing? What about `UnauthorizedAccessException ^ uae)`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should catch by CLI pointer:

```
catch (UnauthorizedAccessException^ uae)
```

Comment: That yields basically the same error: unable to throw or catch by value or reference and inaccessible destructor/ constructor.

Comment: That works, thanks. Can you explain to me what exactly I'm doing? Greatly appreciated.

Comment: @webdreamer: It seems that you were lying about the language you're programming in. This isn't C++, but rather C++/CLI, a Microsoft language.

Comment: I've altered the tags. Thanks. Is there any good readings on C++/CLI I could use? I obviously need to know better.

Comment: There's already this stackoverflow thread, but if you guys have any recommendation, would still like to hear about it http://stackoverflow.com/questions/317217/c-cli-books